# AngularJS2 Losing binding after pipe filter

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a simple ngFor to display a list of items and filter it with a pipe.

The problem is that if i use the pipe and delete an item, it dos selete it from the array but the display isn't updating.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ydWRgMgyIYt9YFOGYaln?p=preview)

My pipe code:

```
class MyFilterPipe {
   transform(list,remove){
      return list.filter((item)=>item.name != remove);
   }
}
```

The template code:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="#item of list |myFilter:'F' ">{{item.name}} <button  (click)="deleteMe(item)">Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks
Avi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There are two categories of [pipes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html): **pure** and **impure**.
>
> Angular executes a pure pipe **only when it detects a pure change** to the input value. A pure change is either a change to a primitive input value (String, Number, Boolean, Symbol) or a changed object reference (Date, Array, Function, 
>   Object).
>
> Angular executes an impure pipe during **every component change detection cycle.** An impure pipe will be called a lot, as often as every keystroke or mouse-move.

`Slice` method is not changing reference of `list` array, since your pipe is **pure**, angular **does not** execute pipe and no display is updated.

Use impure pipe

```
@Pipe({
   name: 'myFilter',
   pure: false
})
```

or change `list` property reference while removing item out of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explenation and solution